# get the text to speak duration of a message (javascript, SpeechSynthesisUtterance, chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, text-to-speech

Is it possible to get the time that is needed to read a specific message ? I would like to use the SpeechSynthesisUtterance Web API and it only has to work in google chrome.

Would it be recommendet to use a third party libary ? Is it viable to messure the time in the background ?

Answer (score 1):

For a workaround (using `SpeechSynthesisUtterance`) I meassure the time with the help of the `onend` event. This is not feasible for all situations, since it will take some time to meassure and is not very precise. You could increase the speed (up to 10) but it will get very unprecise.

```
var speed = 2;
var text = "Test";
var speech = new SpeechSynthesisUtterance(text);
var speakDuration;

speech.volume = 0;
speech.rate = speed;

speech.onend = function (event) {
    speakDuration = event.elapsedTime / speed;
    console.log(speakDuration)
};

window.speechSynthesis.speak(speech);
```