Progress control in Web Speech API
I am using Web Speech API to read a text (documentation link here).
Is there a way of displaying this kind of progress control?

The idea is that user sees the progress of the read, and can jump to any point of it.
Any free alternative is also welcomed.
Thanks in advance!

Look this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52744857/get-the-text-to-speak-duration-of-a-message-javascript-speechsynthesisutteranc

Thank you @EzioMercer! It looks like there is no built-in solution then...
